# Javascript - How to access the array object in Angular js expression? (ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Javascript

```
<script>    
var car=[  
  {
   name:'honda',
   color:'red',
   comments:[
    {
     rating:3,
     bidprice:"25,000"
    },
    {
     rating:4,
     bidprice="21,000"
    ]
   }
  ];
</script>
```

What am i trying to do is getting the bid price of car from each comments by using ng-repeat.
I did try like this

```
<li ng-repeat="car in carList">
  {{car.comments.bidprice}}
</li>
```

Unfortunately, I getting nothing respond from this code.
What should I do?
Thanks you.

Comment: Can you add your HTML that contains the `ng-repeat` to the question?

Comment: Sorry, just updated the ng-repeat. I am new to Angular JS.

Comment: `comments` is an array. You're going to have to `ng-repeat` over `car.comments`

Comment: so what you saying is using <li ng-repeat ="car.comments in carList"> rather than using <li ng-repeat="car in carList"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="comment in car.comments">
  {{comment.bidprice}}
</li>
```

Should work. I am not sure where you took carList from.

Comment: <li ng-repeat="bidprice in car.comments"> {{bidprice.bidprice}} </li> are we able to do like this? I am not sure how to declare.

Comment: Yes that should work, but I would use 'comment' since you are looping through comments

Answer (score 0):

**comments is an array**. or you do like this car.comments[0].bidprice or you do another ng-repat="comment in car.comments".

Comment: Yeah, i try car.comments[0].bidprice before but if i want using ng-repeat to  get all the bid price rather than type two times car.comments[0].bidprice and car.comments[1].bidprice. Sorry for poor english.

Comment: vicky do you have one car with many comments that you want to display or do you have N cars and you want to display for each car its comments?

Comment: Yeah I only got one car with many comment and inside the comments got bidprice this attribute. I am trying to use ng-repeat to display all the bidprice.Thanks you.

Comment: vicky then, your car above is an array but it isn't right like this, so your car trasform in a object(var car={....}) and then try this:                       <li ng-repeat="comment in car.comments">
  {{comment.bidprice}}
</li>

Comment: Thanks you. I did try "comment in car.comments", its work well!